# догрузить остаточные посты при ограничении постов load more wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

У меня на сайте используется ajax загрузка постов по принципу load more при скроллинге. Загружаться может до тех пор, пока не загрузятся все посты. Заказчик попросил установить ограничение на количество загружаемых постов. У меня это почти получилось. Но есть одна проблема:

Посты загружаются по 8 или по 9 штук за одну прокрутку. И например, я ограничил загрузку до 20 постов. Проблема в том, что код загрузит только кратно 8 или 9 штук постов - 16 или 18. Так же, если я ограничу до 30 постов, то загрузятся только 24, если по 8, и 27 постов, если по 9 загружать. НО как догрузить оставшиеся, не могу понять?! Т.е. ограничение на 20, загружаю по 8, в итоге 16 постов. А остальные 4 не загружаются.

Пожалуйста, помогите решить данную проблему. Или хотя бы дайте подсказку.

Спасибо!

Вот код ajax:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        let ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>';
        let section_posts = 1;
        let postData = new FormData();
        let scroll_state = true;
        let loader = document.querySelector('.articlefeed_loader');
        let height_footer = document.querySelector('.site-footer').getBoundingClientRect().height;
        //let max_posts = <?php print json_encode(get_limit_val())?>;

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            if (scroll_state == true) {
                if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= (document.body.offsetHeight - height_footer)) {
                    postData.append('action', 'loadmore');
                    postData.append('paged', section_posts);
                    postData.append('posts_per_page', <?php echo $posts_per_page;?>);
                    postData.append('cats', <?php print json_encode(get_selected_cats())?>);
                    postData.append('max_posts', <?php print json_encode(get_limit_val())?>);

                    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('POST', ajaxurl);
                        xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function (data) {
                            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                                document.querySelector('.articlefeed_template_wrap').innerHTML += data.target.responseText;
                            } else {}
                        });            
                    xhr.send(postData);
                    scroll_state = false;
                    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        scroll_state = true;
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Это хуки в function.php:

function loadmore_get_posts(){

```
  $post_limit = $_POST['max_posts'];
  $paged = !empty($_POST['paged']) ? $_POST['paged'] : 1;
    $paged++;

  $args = array(
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST['posts_per_page'],
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'cat' => $_POST['cats']
  );

  $data = new WP_Query( $args );
 
  $i = 0;
  while( $data->have_posts() && ($post_limit >= $_POST['posts_per_page']*($paged-1) + $i)) : $data->the_post();
      get_template_part( 'templates/content/templates/feeds/articlefeed_item' );
    $i++;
  endwhile;
  die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'loadmore_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'loadmore_get_posts');
```

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум - перед отображением постов в js проверять, сколько уже отображено, сколько осталось догрузить. Например, вы загрузили и отобразили две страницы по 8 постов. Грузите третью, видите, что осталось отобразить 4 поста из загруженных 8, отображаете только их.

Comment: @br3t, спасибо за ответ, но мне кажется я так и делаю - `if (max_posts >= section_posts * <?php echo $posts_per_page; ?>) {document.querySelector('.box').innerHTML += data.target.responseText; }`. Или я не прав? Поправьте, если что, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы считаете страницами, а не постами. Но у вас нужно переделывать структуру в этом случае, т.к. вы получаете все посты одним куском - либо отдавать из РНР в виде JSON отдельные посты, либо предварительно разбирать полученный из аякса кусок на отдельные посты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как-то так должно работать:

```
function loadmore_get_posts(){
  
  $post_limit = 20; // хардкод для удобства чтения. Можете получать его из $_POST
  $paged = !empty($_POST['paged']) ? $_POST['paged'] : 1;
  $paged++;

  $args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $_POST['posts_per_page'],
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => $_POST['cats']
  );

  $data = new WP_Query( $args );
  $i = 0;
  while( $data->have_posts() && ($post_limit >= $_POST['posts_per_page']*($paged-1) + $i)) :
    $data->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'templates/...' );
    $i++;
  endwhile;
  die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'loadmore_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'loadmore_get_posts');
```

В таком варианте гоняем меньше данных (обрезаем на стороне сервера, а не на стороне браузера). В JS Тогда убираем проверку и рисуем всё, что нам прислал сервер. Если аякс вернёт пустоту - снимаем обработчик скролла, чтобы лишний раз сервер не запрашивать.

И я бы разморозку скролла по таймауту убрал бы (перенёс внутрь ответа аякса) - в медленных сетях аякс может возвращать данные более одной секунды и разморозив скролл по таймауту мы можем запросить следующую пачку постов, не дождавшись загрузки предыдущей.

Comment: Как говорят на англоязычном stackoverflow - "Работает как Шарм" :) Спасибо огромное, друг!